# instantiate by reflection

Tags: go, reflection

Given a function with a parameter (that is a pointer to a struct) I want to instantiate a type of this parameter.

For example, for this function:

```
func MyFunction(myStruct *MyStruct) {}
```

using reflection I want to create a variable that contains exactly same as `x := &MyStruct{}` would contain.

This is the code example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyStruct struct {
}

func main () {
    reflectedFunction := reflect.TypeOf(MyFunction)
    argType := reflectedFunction.In(0)

    reflectedParameter := reflect.New(argType)
    actual := reflectedParameter.Interface()
    fmt.Println(actual)

    expected := &MyStruct{}
    fmt.Println(expected)
}

func MyFunction(myStruct *MyStruct) {
}
```

If you execute it, you'll see that they contain different info:

```
0xc00000e028 // actual
&{} // expected
```

This question isn't about why I would like to do this, so please avoid recommending not doing it, etc.

Comment: see this play https://play.golang.org/p/Nyuc0mYmgkZ

Comment: aren't the same

Comment: I managed to have the "same" value using Elem().Interface(), the print isn't returning exactly the same, but seems that the content are actually the same (checked with the printf %#v)

Comment: read all the commetns and answer. This has been subject to debate...

Comment: @fj123x. `Elem().Interface()` gives you the same _type_, however it is still a nil pointer. You have to use `reflect.New` with the correct type in the first place. You cannot get an actual variable of `*MyStruct` dynamically, because types are defined at compile time, so you will have to settle for an interface containing that type.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `actual` is a `interface{}` value containing a `*MyStruct`. As the name and documentation indicate, `reflectedParameter.Interface()` returns an `interface{}`.

> using reflection I want to create a variable that contains exactly same as `x := &MyStruct{}` would contain.

Then you'll have to type assert it:

```
actual := reflectedParameter.Elem().Interface().(*MyStruct)
```

Comment: nop, you need .Elem().Interface()  https://play.golang.org/p/r5i3tvlD8He

Comment: @mh-cbon, nope, you need `reflect.New(argType.Elem())`

Comment: @mh-cbon that will still yield a value of type `interface{}`, not a value of type `&MyStruct` as the question states.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I can't do the type assertion, this is why I'm using reflection

Comment: @fj123x if you can't do the type assertion, then you cannot meet your stated requirement. Variable types are defined at compile time, only value types can change at runtime.

Answer (score -1):

[`reflect.New`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#New) creates a pointer to a new zero value of the reflected type. In your example that type is already a `*MyStruct`, so the value of your `actual` winds up being a representation of a `**MyStruct`, as seen in https://play.golang.org/p/Nyuc0mYmgkZ. Taking the `.Elem()` of that results in the correct type again, but you end up with a `nil` pointer `(*MyStruct)(nil)`.

You need to take the `.Elem()` if that first type if you want to create a new pointer value.

```
reflectedParameter := reflect.New(argType.Elem())
```

https://play.golang.org/p/QzwTFUH3HTs

```
reflectedFunction := reflect.TypeOf(MyFunction)
argType := reflectedFunction.In(0)

reflectedParameter := reflect.New(argType.Elem())
actual := reflectedParameter.Interface()
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", actual)

expected := &MyStruct{}
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", expected)
```

Which prints

```
&main.MyStruct{}
&main.MyStruct{}
```

Comment: This does not fit "I want to create a variable that contains exactly same as x := &MyStruct{} would contain." This yields an `interface{}`, what OP describes would yield a `*MyStruct`.

Comment: @Adrian i dont really agree to this argument, as going down that path (reflection) you will stick to interface

Comment: @Adrian: This does create a `*MyStruct` typed value, which you can see in the example. Passing the `interface{}` to the `fmt.Printf` `interface{}` argument, or asserting it first makes no difference.

Comment: The value is an interface value containing a `*MyStruct`. It is not *exactly the same as* `x := &MyStruct{}`. It is exactly the same as `var x interface{} = &MyStruct`.

Comment: @Adrian, well obviously you cannot get a typed value without a type assertion, but the primary error in the question is because the user created a `**MyStruct`